# Mutually inclusive and possibily Mutually exclusive issue with options

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

Listing a product that is in two pieces, with options for each. If an option for "A" is selected, only "A" will be added to the cart. if option for "B" is added, then only "B". If option for "A" and "B" are selected, then both "A" and "B" is added as a single line item.

A simple example: https://ujena.com.br/index.php/rockstar-veneziana-614.html

It seems that an option can be either "mandatory" or "optional". Setting all options to "optional" solves the problem, however introduces the problem of having an item added with no options. Is there a way to make the options one or the other, or both, but at least one? Option "A"

Or option "B" solution, where is the option checking code for post data? I can recode the check function in the receiver of the post data.